# How to Pause Javascript Execution

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, pause

I have an array of elements I want to iterate through, addClass to each DOM element in question, take it away with removeClass 1 second later, then move onto the next element in the array and do the same.

What happens instead is that all elements in array have the addClass applied all at once, then each one is removed in order, 1 second apart. So the removeClass line is working, but I can't figure out why the addClass is not. I can manually input the number of MS for addClass and that will work as expected.

```
function runSequence () {    
  randomSequence();    
  for (let i = 0, timer=0; i < sequence.length; i++) {    
    setTimeout(function () { $('.' + sequence[i]).addClass('button-press'); }, (timer * 1000));
    setTimeout(function() { $('.' + sequence[i]).removeClass('button-press'); }, ((timer++) * 1000));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to `await` a Promise every time you want to delay instead:

```js
const sequence = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'buzz'];
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function runSequence() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    const $elm = $('.' + sequence[i]);
    $elm.addClass('button-press');
    await delay(1000);
    $elm.removeClass('button-press');
  }
}

runSequence();
```

```css
.button-press {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">div</div>
<div class="bar">div</div>
<div class="baz">div</div>
<div class="buzz">div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait, you are using jQuery... it will find all and add the class to all.

You need to loop through each item one by one.

By the way as @ggorlen pointed out, you need `++timer` or else the `removeClass` happens the same event cycle as the `addClass`.

(but do you mean all of the addClass was done for `sequence[0], sequence[1], ...`?)

Comment: Also, `timer++` means it'll have the same timeout as the add `timer`. I think OP wanted `++timer`?

Comment: `timer++` or `++timer` both equate the same value. `removeClass` is working fine for removing classes element by element, in sequence with the correct duration between. `addClass` is not working however.

Comment: @CliftonHill try `timer = 0; console.log(timer * 1000); console.log((timer++) * 1000);` and then `timer = 0; console.log(timer * 1000); console.log((++timer) * 1000);`

Comment: Good point @nopole, but while `++timer` has an immediate effect on the value, `timer++` still does increase the value, just not at that moment, and I'm not sure why. Either way, the removeClass was working, though it may have had an issue I had missed (as per your point and @ggorlen).